# JavaScript: Dynamically injecting and removing html pages

Tags: javascript, cordova, dynamic-html

I'm developing a Phonegap/Cordova application and having serious performance issues. I'm looking into a tutorial and the author is recommending dynamic creation of html pages using JavaScript.

here's a link of the tutorial:
http://coenraets.org/blog/phonegap-tutorial/

scrolling down to part 4:
"A single page application is a web application that lives within a single HTML page. The 'views' of the application are **injected into- and removed from the DOM as needed as the user navigates through the app.**"

I understand the creation part, but how are the pages being **removed** from the DOM???

Code by Christopher Coenraets:

```
renderHomeView: function() {
  var html =
        "<div class='header'><h1>Home</h1></div>" +
        "<div class='search-view'>" +
        "<input class='search-key'/>" +
        "<ul class='employee-list'></ul>" +
        "</div>"
  $('body').html(html);
  $('.search-key').on('keyup', $.proxy(this.findByName, this));
},
```

The initialize function:

```
initialize: function() {
  var self = this;
  this.store = new MemoryStore(function() {
     self.renderHomeView();
  });
}
```

I don't see any function that removes the HomeView after rendering it.

please help me figure this out as I've been going over it for days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JQuery method "$('body').html(string);" sets the content of the 'body' tag in the html code to whatever the string specifies. Meaning previous content inside the body tag will be removed from the DOM.

You can also remove specific elements from the DOM using another JQuery method called remove(). This is the method he uses later in the tutorial when implementing sliding between html pages.

*There are updated versions of the tutorial you linked to http://ccoenraets.github.io/cordova-tutorial/create-cordova-project.html.*

Comment: I must have missed the remove() function .. Thank you @Forss

Comment: the remove() function also remove the selector. Should use html('') as my suggestion below there.

Answer (score 2):

first, create an *.html page with your content.
store it on root as /html/homeview.html

homeview.html

```
    <div class='header'>
       <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
       <div class='search-view'>
       <input class='search-key'/>
       <ul class='employee-list'></ul>
    </div>
```

index.html, you've :

```
     <div class="homeView"></div>
```

And implement the jQuery ajax or simple $.get() :

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $.get('html/homeView.html')
         .done(function(data) { //this is homeView's HTML content
             $('.homeView').html(data);
         })
         .fail(function(error) {
             console.log(error);
         })
   })
```

remove its content by

```
    $('.homeView').html('');
```

Comment: Thank you for your input but it seems in the tutorial that this is automated as the user navigates to another page.. so that's what I'm trying to figure out

Comment: So for your question, how to remove from DOM, just $('body').html('') <== just input double ', nothing inside. If you want to create single-page application as the tutorial, do as my code above, you could get another page then input it dynamictically in view with another URL such as '/html/user.html', '/html/admin.html'. do not store strings as their example, it's just example.

Comment: I am not an expert in Jquery, but will try to do a logical explanation. For a simple App normally HTML fragments ( `div element`) are added to the HTML DOM ( HTML document). The DIVs are hidden and only one of them are visible at any given time. So when a user moves from a view to another view, the previous view is hidden and the new view is displayed with some transition logic ( slide/fade). In a large App containing many views the HTML fragments are added and removed dynamically to reduce the DOM document size. I hope you have understood what I am trying to convey.

Comment: I got what you suggest @frank, but seem this guys need to render it by javascript, instead of toggle his pages.

Comment: I was trying to explain my comments to @Aous1000.

Comment: @JhKaiz I understand you perfectly .. Your way is the way I would do it, I've also been using frank's suggestions. But I'm still learning my way around JavaScript so I'm checking out all the recommendations that could boost performance and save me some coding time :) since my app can get quite big over 10 pages do you. I guess my real question is how is the the author doing it in the tutorial or is he even doing it at all .. can you see any clues in the [link](http://coenraets.org/blog/phonegap-tutorial/) I've provided??

Comment: @Aous1000 that is a tough tutorial to start with at least for a beginner. If you understand the tutorial, You will be able to understand what most frameworks do under the hood. Basically the author is using Handlebar templates ( HTML files without the head and body tag) that act as the view that will be loaded via AJAX as and when needed. Once loaded they will be transitioned to the loaded view. I think the function `HomeView.template()` loads the `Homeview template` file, the same goes for `HomeView.liTemplate(employees)` which renders the template with employee data.

Comment: @frank I agree .. very tough tutorial, but I figured it covers all the parts that I would need later on .. So like you said I think handlebars is the one that is actually doing the removing -or at least replacing views- behind the scenes. Thanks alot